# How to run background task (using DbContext with Entity Framework) on Controller with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I'm using dependency injection to pass in `MyDbContext`.

In `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`, I'm using

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

So in my controller's constructor I can do:

`public MyController(MyDbContext context)`

In one of the HTTP methods, I'm using the `MyDbContext` to make some database changes, but then I would like to fire off a "long-running" task to make some more database changes.  I can't use the same `MyDbContext` instance (scope would dispose of it before the task would complete), so is there a way of passing in multiple (or some kind of factory to generate) `MyDbContext` instances with the same settings as the `MyDbContext` that is currently being passed through dependency injection?  Or is that even the right approach?  I'm about to drop EF and just use standard SQL.

I'm using ASP Core.

Thanks!

Comment: You should really use a library designed for that specific task, like [hangfire.io](https://www.hangfire.io/). It has built-in support for DI.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma my question still stands then?  I would have to pass it a `MyDbContext`, no?

Comment: Yes, but by using hangfire you will decouple task scheduling from task execution. You need to manage the lifecycle of your dependencies. [This](http://nance.io/dotnet/core/async/2016/08/19/long-running-tasks-in-dotnet-core-with-hangfire.html) is a good starting example.